# A part of classes in CSS-file doesn't work (J2EE)

Tags: html, css, jakarta-ee

really need help. I have created a CSS file in a project in NetBeans:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.logo{
   display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.search_image{
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
}
.sidebar1{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.book_list{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

It is linked with a JSP file. First four classes really work, but 2 last ones don't (search_image and sidebar1). When I try to check the CSS file in Inspect element in Chrome I see the next:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.main {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
}

.logo{
   display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
}

.search_image{
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

What could be the reason that the CSS file is deployed on a server partly?

Comment: Could it be you are looking at an old version of the CSS file that is still in cache?

Comment: yes, that was a problem! thanx! I didn't know about cash :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it keeps the old CSS in the cache. I recommend that you turn off cache when inspector is open. You can find it in the setting of inspector.

Comment: yes, you are right! I didn't know about cash... thanx!